# how to compare all elements in list using unique() c++

Tags: c++, string, list, compare, unique

I need delete all same words(words are the same if they start with the same letter) 
My compare function does next:

```
H  J
J  H
H  I
```

Therefore, I need each letter to be compared with the other

```
 bool compare(string a, string b) {
        cout << a.front() << "  " << b.front() << endl;
        return(a.front() == b.front());
    }
    void Fifth_task(list <string>& lst) {
        list <string> ::iterator it;
        lst.unique(compare);
        for (it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it) {
            cout << *it << endl;
        }
    }


    int main(){
    list <string> first;
    first.push_back("Hello");
    first.push_back("Johnny");
    first.push_back("Hello");
    first.push_back("Ildar");
    Fifth_task(first);
    return 0;
    }
```

in the end i should get 3 words : Hello , Johnny, Ildar
How can i do it?

Comment: [`std::list::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/unique) returns _consecutive_ duplicate elements.  So you'll either need to sort your list before calling unique, or use a different method if the order must be maintained.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i need the same order

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique), unique will...

> Eliminates all except the first element **from every consecutive group** of equivalent elements from the range
>
> <sub><sup>(emphasis mine)</sup></sub>

In the example on that page, calling `unique()` on `{1,2,1,1,3,3,3,4,5,4}` will yield `{1 2 1 3 4 5 4 x x x}`. Notice how the duplicate 1's and 4's are not removed. This is because they're not in a "consecutive group."

So to ensure that your words starting with the same letter are all in "consecutive groups," sort your list first:

```
 void Fifth_task(list <string>& lst) {
    lst.sort();
    lst.unique(compare);
    // ...
```

See it in action here: https://ideone.com/1i48nj

Comment: but i need the same order

Answer (score 0):

`std::list::unique` removes adjacent duplicates. The predicate you give it is for comparing the equality of adjacent items. That's not what you want since you want to compare an item with all previous items.

What you can do is use the `list::remove_if` instead, using a set to keep a record of first letters already seen. So I would change your `Fifth_task` function to be like this:

```
void Fifth_task(std::list<std::string>& lst) {
    std::list<std::string>::iterator it;
    std::set<char> seen;
    lst.remove_if([&](const std::string& s) {
        char c = std::tolower(s[0]);
        bool remove = (seen.count(c) > 0);
        seen.insert(c);
        return remove; });

    for (it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Working version here: https://godbolt.org/z/WLwQeZ